# Product rule for bras and kets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

For the time evolution of expectation value of an operator $\Omega$, we can write

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi|\Omega |\psi\rangle=\langle\dot\psi|\Omega|\psi\rangle+\langle\psi|\dot\Omega|\psi\rangle+\langle\psi|\Omega|\dot\psi\rangle$$

by the product rule. How can we show that this is true in the $|x\rangle$ basis?

I tried
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi|\Omega |\psi\rangle=\frac{d}{dt}\int\langle\psi|x\rangle\langle x|\Omega|x'\rangle\langle x'|\psi\rangle dxdx'=\frac{d}{dt}\int\psi(x,t)^*\langle x|\Omega|x'\rangle\psi(x',t)dxdx'$$

How do I proceed to express $\langle x|\Omega|x'\rangle$ in terms of $x$, $x'$ and $t$ if I don't know what $\Omega$ is?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. If you don't know what $\Omega$ is, why would you be able to come up with a more explicit expression than $\langle x|\Omega|x'\rangle$? You could define $\langle x|\Omega(t)|x'\rangle \equiv \Omega(x,x',t)$ where the latter is a linear operator on position-basis wavefunctions, but that's just notation.

Comment: @J.Murray Since $\langle x|\psi \rangle$ can be expressed as $\psi(x)$, I'm thinking to express $\langle x | \Omega | x' \rangle$ as something like $f(x,x')$. So that I can perform differentiation using product rule in calculus. But then I wouldn't know how to deal with the double integral if the term is general like $f(x,x')$. Ultimately I want to get an expression like $\frac{d}{dt}\int \psi(x)^* f(x) \psi(x) dx$.

Comment: It is not possible in general to obtain such an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically we define the notation $\langle x|\hat \Omega(t) | x'\rangle \equiv \Omega(x,x',t)$, where $\hat \Omega(t)$ is a (generally time-dependent)  abstract operator and $\Omega(x,x',t)$ is an operator which acts on wavefunctions in the position basis.  A common example is the momentum operator:
$$\langle x|\hat P|x'\rangle = \delta(x-x') \frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{dx'}$$

As a result, $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle x|\hat\Omega(t)|x'\rangle = \langle x |\frac{d\hat\Omega(t)}{dt}|x'\rangle \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Omega(x,x',t)$$

---

It should also be noted that we can differentiate abstract operators without moving to a basis.  The operator $\frac{d}{dt}\hat\Omega(t)$ is the operator such that

$$\frac{d\hat\Omega}{dt}|\psi\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{\hat \Omega(t+\epsilon)|\psi\rangle-\hat\Omega(t)|\psi\rangle}{\epsilon}$$
We can evaluate this in a basis if we wish, but there's no particular need to.